# Setting user agent of a java URLConnection

Tags: java, user-agent

I'm trying to parse a webpage using Java with URLConnection. I try to set up the user-agent like this:

```
java.net.URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

But the resulting user agent is the one I specify, with "Java/1.5.0_19" appended to the end. Is there a way to truly set the user agent without this addition?

Comment: How do you know that's the resulting user-agent? Where are you seeing it?

Comment: By fetching it with PHP and displaying it on the page that is being grabbed by Java.

Comment: This actually works now, see the second answer.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Off hand, setting the `http.agent` system property to `""` might do the trick (I don't have the code in front of me).

You might get away with:

```
 System.setProperty("http.agent", "");
```

but that might require a race between you and initialisation of the URL protocol handler, if it caches the value at startup (actually, I don't think it does).

The property can also be set through JNLP files (available to applets from 6u10) and on the command line:

```
-Dhttp.agent=
```

Or for wrapper commands:

```
-J-Dhttp.agent=
```

Comment: How would I do that? c.setRequestProperty("http.agent","");? I'm assuming somewhere else...

Comment: yeah... that work like a charm!

just do a:

System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

And you're ready to go!! :)

Answer (score 97):

Just for clarification: `setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla ...")` now works just fine and doesn't append `java/xx` at the end! At least with Java 1.6.30 and newer.

I listened on my machine with netcat(a port listener):

```
$ nc -l -p 8080
```

It simply listens on the port, so you see anything which gets requested, like raw http-headers.

And got the following http-headers without setRequestProperty:

```
GET /foobar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_30
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

And WITH setRequestProperty:

```
GET /foobar HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see the user agent was properly set.

Full example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class TestUrlOpener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/foobar");
        URLConnection hc = url.openConnection();
        hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

        System.out.println(hc.getContentType());
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, if one still uses Java 1.5

Comment: @Dejell Are you suggesting this approach is outdated? I am using Java 7 and this did exactly what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 5):

its work for me 
**set the User-Agent in the addRequestProperty.**

```
URL url = new URL(<URL>);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
```

Comment: No need to cast to HttpURLConnection.

Comment: @jechterhoff it's required in Java 8

Comment: @FonzTech I don't see why the cast would be required in Java 8. The following works in my program (compliance is Java 1.8):URL clSourceUrl = new URL(clSource);
URLConnection urlConn = clSourceUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"); Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @jechterhoff the user who gave the answer used `HttpURLConnection`. You would have been right if he used `URLConnection`. Anyway, if you try to compile this line `HttpURLConnection c = new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();` for example, `javac` will give you `error: incompatible types` on that line. I'm using Java 1.8.0 r172, so the most recent release of Java 8

Comment: @FonzTech Ah, now I see what you mean. I should have been more precise in my first comment (sorry about that): What I was trying to say is that you don't need to use HttpURLConnection at all here. Apparently you can also just use a URLConnection, as shown in my previous comment. I thought that this could improve the answer a tiny bit. In any case, you are right that `HttpURLConnection c = new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();` certainly requires a cast to HttpURLConnection - in Java 8 and also previous versions of Java.

Comment: @jechterhoff Don't worry. You are right about `HttpURLConnection` being overkill here, but since the user who gave the answer used it, the casting to the derived class was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Servers tend to reject old browsers and systems.

The page   [Tech Blog (wh): Most Common User Agents](https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/) reflects the user-agent property of your current browser in section *"Your user agent is:"*, which can be applied to set the request property "User-Agent" of a `java.net.URLConnection` or the system property "http.agent".