# Java: File type of `url.openStream()`

Tags: java, file, url, stream

I wrote this this method to download a webpage given a URL.  It is designed to download HTML only.  If I want to do error checking and allow HTML only how should I do this?

```
public static String download(URL url) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String page = "";
    String line;    
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        page = page + line;
    }
    return page;
}
```

Originally I was planning on doing this:

```
String file = url.getFile();
if(file.subString(file.indexOf("."),file.length()-1).equalsIgnoreCase("HTML")){
    // do method
```

However the URL: `http://www.smu.com` returns `""` for `url.getFile()`.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test if you're getting html you can use URL.openConnection() to get a UrlConnection can then call getContentType() which should return "text/html" for an HTML page.  You can then use the getInputStream() method on the UrlConnection() as a drop in replacement for url.openStream();

If you actually want to validate that the content the server is sending you is HTML you'd need to find an HTML validation library.  I don't know of one off-hand, sorry.

Something to consider, which may be why www.smu.com returns no data, is that a number of websites will serve different data depending on the User-Agent string sent on the HTTP connection.  You may need to modify that on your UrlConnection with: UrlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", ...);   See more info here : [Setting user agent of a java URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection)

Comment: smu.com does return data, the URL just has no file part (after the slash)

Comment: @Bart The request tries to fetch "/" which the web-server happily returns "/index.html" for (this is dependent upon the web-server and configuration of such -- it might just have happily returned a 404, but that isn't friendly for web-users). It doesn't explain "no data", but it does explain why you don't need "the full path". See my answer for more (although accept this answer already).

Comment: @pst: I know, it's what I said but you said it much better

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check the content *beyond* checking the `Content-Type` header, then you can use an HTML parser such as (the misleadingly named!) [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

"http://www.smu.com" sends you the data in "http://www.smu.com/index.html". This is the (common) behavior of web-servers when "/" is requested (a web-server could also theoretically redirect one with a 302 or whatnot). Checking to see if the URL ends in ".html" is thus entirely silly (not to mention that it could be a ".php", ".asp" or whatever).

However, a *nice* web-server serving up HTML should return return a `Content-Type` header of "text/html". (This is of course assuming it's returning HTML and not XHTML or XML or whatnot and the web-server is not broken).

You will likely want to use [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). Here is an [example of URLConnection with headers](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/URLConnectionopenStreamismorepowerfulthanURLopenStream.htm).

How did I determine the top bit?

I ran `curl -I http://www.smu.com` (and with ../index.html) and compared the results. They look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 19 Oct 2010 18:01:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Jan 2010 20:27:52 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2993
Content-Type: text/html
```