# Java: Download from an URL

Tags: java, url

Could someone try my codes out? It was working a few days ago and now it's not. I did not modify anything, and so I suspect the webmaster of that side has block me. Could someone check it out for me? This is part of my school project.

```
public class Cost extends TimerTask{

public void run() {
  Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
  Integer hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

  if (hour==1) {
    try {
      URL tariff = new URL("http://www.emcsg.com/MarketData/PriceInformation?downloadRealtime=true");
      ReadableByteChannel tar = Channels.newChannel(tariff.openStream());
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.csv");
      fos.getChannel().transferFrom(tar, 0, 1<<24);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Cost.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
  }

  else {

  }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I do, but I don't think it's because of this though. java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\test.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: I was supposed to use these code to download the file first before my other codes can process it..but damn, I super pissed off because it doesn't download anymore.....................

Comment: I can manually download using a browser, but my whole idea was to make it auto download....

Comment: Well, if you get to line `fos.getChannel().transferFrom(tar, 0, 1<<24);` (I guess the FileNotFoundException is thrown here) you could already open a stream so the problem seems to be elsewhere. Please fix all exceptions, even if you think they're not related. If they really aren't they might still hide the actual problem.

Comment: if you can download in a browser then you're probably not blocked

Comment: If you can hit it in a browser then you're probably not blocked, unless the website is checking your User-Agent header. You can always set a user-agent header to match your browser but it's a bit cheeky.

Comment: oh god, this is irritating me, I just screen my codes, and even use my old working codes, but it's not working...could someone please help me test these codes out.... :<

Comment: try Paul's suggestion of setting `user-agent`, may be the site identified your program as a bot.

Comment: I tried this java.net.URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7");

but netbeans wasn't able to identify url.open connection

Comment: Try setting it as "http.agent" system property instead - see my answer below. And it should probably be tariff.openConnection()

Answer (score 4):

First of all, clean up your IO exceptions as that might be obscuring the problem - check you can write to D:.

If you are being blocked by the site because of your user-agent header:

This will show you your user-agent header: http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php. Then the answer to [Setting user agent of a java URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection) tells you how to set your header.

You will either need to add a step between instantiating URL and opening stream:

```
URL tariff = new URL("http://www.emcsg.com/MarketData/PriceInformation?downloadRealtime=true");
java.net.URLConnection c = tariff.openConnection();
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", " USER AGENT STRING HERE ");
ReadableByteChannel tar = Channels.newChannel(c.getInputStream());
```

or you could try just doing this:

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", " USER AGENT STRING HERE ");
```

sometime before you call `openStream()`.

Edit: This works for me. Can you try running it and let us know the output:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

    public class TestURL {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
              URL tariff = new URL("http://www.emcsg.com/MarketData/PriceInformation?downloadRealtime=true");
              URLConnection c = tariff.openConnection();
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
              System.out.println(br.readLine());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks paul, I'm trying it now

Comment: sorry if I'm noob, the setting up of the user agent  header, which part are u referring to?

Comment: Put `System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7");` in a line or two before `if (hour==1) {`

Comment: oh no, it still didn't work...could I space my modified code here?

Comment: System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7");
    if (hour==2) {
            try {
                URL tariff = new URL("http://www.emcsg.com/MarketData/PriceInformation?downloadRealtime=true");
    java.net.URLConnection c = tariff.openConnection();
    c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7 ");

Comment: 'ReadableByteChannel tar = Channels.newChannel(c.getInputStream());'
    'FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Tariff.csv");'
     'fos.getChannel().transferFrom(tar, 0, 1<<13);'

Comment: No, needs to be one approach or the other, not both. Just comment out `c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7 "); ` and try again.

Comment: I did attempt to remove the exception earlier on, but it was still the same. I think it's definitely the webserver that is blocking me as a bot

Comment: I comment out that line, still couldn't download

Comment: sorry for the trouble, on my part, I'm also trying how to figure this out.

Comment: You *are* running the java process on the same machine as the browser that *can* access the page? Is it the same machine and location / connection that worked OK earlier?

Comment: yes, I'm running the java process on the same machine as the browser. It worked well 2 days ago, same machine and same location.

Comment: Please try the example in my last edit and let us know the output.

Comment: Hi paul, I seem to found the error after much attempt, apparently it was link to another .class file, but netbeans did not indicate that error. Thanks for the patience and help! I will give you my vote for all your helpful advices!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and running it I had no problem, everything works fine.
Are you working behind a proxy?

In that case you have to configure it:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxy.name");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Comment: Yes, you can set it there. It's important that it's set berfore you do 'ReadableByteChannel tar = Channels.newChannel(tariff.openStream());', so in main it's ok

Comment: I did try your System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxy.name");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");, but to no avail

Comment: You have to change 'my.proxy.name' with the real name of the proxy and '8080' with the real port. Did you do that?

Comment: when u mean proxy name, do you mean proxy ip?

Comment: System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "155.**.*.1*");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "4****");
I tried with this, but still the same issue

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace of the exception and post it? which line gives the NPE?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\test.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
 at evscheduler.Opencsv.Csvreader(Opencsv.java:29)
 at evscheduler.EVschedulerApp$1$1.run(EVschedulerApp.java:73)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is related to the code you posted? Seems you're trying to read the file you wrote, but you wrote "test.cvs", not "D:\test.csv". Try doing this: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:\\test.csv");

Comment: I just did what you recommended, it couldn't work. The file exception are all due to the later code. By right, my codes should have download and then being processed by other codes. The only download code I have is these code...