# How to get shoutcast source code?

Tags: java, networking, shoutcast

I want to get the source code from a shoutcast. I read the lines with the code below:

```java
try {
    URL game = new URL("http", "somewebsitename", 8013, "index.html");
    URLConnection connection = game.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead of getting the source code which I see with Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer I get these lines:

ICY 404 Resource Not Found
icy-notice1:
SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8
icy-notice2:The resource requested was not found

I made sure the the file exists on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "get the source code from a shoutcast" you mean you want to get the HTML from a SHOUTcast Admin Panel page.

If you want the admin panel, you need to have `Mozilla` somewhere in your User-Agent string.  Once you set your User-Agent appropriately, you'll have no problem.

```
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/Your-Applicaton-Name");
```

See also:  [Setting user agent of a java URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection)