# How to set user agent in: new XmlSlurper().parse(URL)

Tags: groovy, user-agent, xmlslurper

I am launching requests to a web service using [Groovy/XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper):

```
new XmlSlurper().parse("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=...")
```

I would like to set the user agent to let the website know what project the requests are from.

How to set the user agent?

- [XMLSlurper's constructors](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#constructor_summary) do not have anything like this.
- The [setProperty method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) sounds interesting but Google does not lead to anything related to UA.
- I would rather avoid changing the code to abandon XmlSlurper in favor of another library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Groovy` uses the JVM's default SAX parser to connect to the input stream and perform the initial parsing. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2529903/357360) on SO that might help - all you need to do is set this before your call to the slurper to make it happen:

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "my-agent-name");
```

P.S. This is just a guess - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see p.3, btw there is also Groovy Http Builder, it uses JsonSlurper for JSON results, but it's much more flexible for making http requests - http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder