# Manually sending GET request to a website. 302 redirect error

Tags: java, http, redirect, get, request

I am currently working on a web scraper using java. I am manually sending the GET request by setting up a tcp connection and using printerwriter.

I am able to connect to most websites such as yahoo.com or cracked.com and receive a response, BUT I am unable to connect to my target website - vinylengine.com. It will always return a 302 error.

I have compared my send request with my browser's and they are nearly identical.

**My header:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.vinylengine.com
```

**My Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2013 19:27:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.nakedresource.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Thu, 20 Jun 2013 19:27:00 GMT
Content-Length: 213
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.nakedresource.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

**Browser's header:**

```
GET http://www.vinylengine.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.vinylengine.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: __utma=72407316.18415374.1370488314.1370497873.1370543389.3; __utmz=72407316.1370488314.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SESSaf8d12283bdbdc5f5bbfb2aef054db6d=1f0676e5cab0ba2c5a80e76ea0bd6f75; __utmc=72407316; has_js=1; __utmb=72407316
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 06 Jun 2013 18:02:53 GMT
If-None-Match: "2186d59ac297e0f1a43433fa61e8a94b"
```

**Code:**

```
public void sendRequest(String extensionString, String urlString)
{  
    try 
    {
        //BufferedReader inFromServer;
        //PrintWriter outToServer;
        //These 2 are initalized elsewhere

        outToServer.println("GET " + extensionString + " HTTP/1.1");
        outToServer.println("Host: " + urlString);

        outToServer.println("");
        outToServer.flush();

        String temp;
        while((temp=inFromServer.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

        return;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.printf("sendRequest failed: %s",e);
        return;
    }
}
```

**I have tried changing the host name to nakedresource.com, but when I do that, I get the page source for nakedresource.com and not vinylengine.com**

Comment: HTTP 302 means redirection so you need to call redirected URL again

Comment: So, you're not doing the same thing as the browser, then wondering why the results are different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site in question is looking at your user agent string (Or lack thereof in your case).

When you say you're doing "almost the same thing" as the browser ... you're right. And computers are kinda picky about things like that.

If you don't supply a `User-Agent:` header you get a redirect.

> > telnet www.vinylengine.com 80
>   Trying 67.225.154.112...
>   Connected to vinylengine.com.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.vinylengine.com
>   Accept: */*
>   
>   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   ...

Whereas if you do provide one, you get the page:

> > telnet www.vinylengine.com 80
>   Trying 67.225.154.112...
>   Connected to vinylengine.com.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.vinylengine.com
>   User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
>   Accept: */*
>   
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   ... (the page)

This is usually done because the site is providing different versions of the content to different browsers as determined by the `User-Agent` header. Apparently their answer to "no User-Agent" is ... punt, and you get redirected to the parent site root.

Comment: +1 Exactly my finding (even down to the same zLib version :).

Answer (score 3):

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

If you are using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) use the code above.

Also refer to [Example showing HTTP redirects](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/)

Comment: Just an FYI, the redirect is because of no `User-Agent` string. It then takes you to a different (parent) site rather than the actual page in question.

Comment: You can always refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection to learn how to add a user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

This could be possible when you have your proxy configured in your browser but your JVM is unaware of it.

Try to start your JVM with the following arguments and see if it fixes the issue:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.12.11.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800
```

Comment: The problem sin't that, the problem is that the site looks for a User Agent string.