# Error Accessing Website

Tags: java, html

I am trying to get the html of MyAnimeList.net (specifically this page: `http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?q=toradora!`), I am using a method that has worked for me before on different websites but doesn't work for me here.

The Method I use:

```
public String getWebsiteSourceCode(String sURL){
try{
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection urlConn= url.openConnection();

        //NEW LINE
         urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();

        return a.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    return "null";
}
}
```

What I get:

`<html><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"></head><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&incident_id=124000930038292057-125560654487356886&edet=12&cinfo=464f095fc75381e904000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 124000930038292057-125560654487356886</iframe></html>`

What I should be getting: The html code of the webpage (I can get it in google chrome by right click + view page source, and it is completely different from what I get from my method).

From what I get, it says something about ROBOTS, so I assume the website has cookies or something to track whether I am using a browser or a bot... What I want to know is whether or not it is possible to bypass this, and how would I go upon doing so? Thanks for your help :) (Preferably in Java, since that is what I am using)

EDIT: tried adding this line:
`urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36");`
but I get the same error...

Comment: Try finding a browser User-Agent and sending that in the headers.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by that. Care to explain further?

Comment: Setting an user agent in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection

OR Let me google that for you: http://bit.ly/1dc1Xg2

Comment: I tried adding a UserAgent, but that didn't work, am i doing it wrong? or what is happening?

Comment: I checked it, it's still not the same as what I get when I use chrome and rightclick + view page source

Comment: @user2310289 I checked their website further and noticed that `MyAnimeList.net` seems to use `https://my.incapsula.com/` which uses a captcha to verify computer users when it thinks you are a bot. The code i get back from the site contains `<META NAME="robots" ...` so it seems that the website knows that it is being accessed by a bot. So is there anyways to bypass it? It worked fine with Google Chrome (Never got to a capcha thing), and I even got JAVAFX's demo browser to work...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
URL url = new URL(sURL);
URLConnection urlConn= url.openConnection();
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "....");
```

For an idea of what to put in `...` have a look at http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

Using your code I get

```
<html><head><META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow"><script>(function(){f
unction getSessionCookies(){cookieArray=new Array();var cName=/^\s?incap_ses_/;v
ar c=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){key=c[i].substr(0,c[
i].indexOf("="));value=c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=")+1,c[i].length);if(cName.tes
t(key)){cookieArray[cookieArray.length]=value}}return cookieArray}function setIn
capCookie(vArray){try{cookies=getSessionCookies();digests=new Array(cookies.leng
th);for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){digests[i]=simpleDigest((vArray)+cookies[i
])}res=vArray+",digest="+(digests.join())}catch(e){res=vArray+",digest="+(encode
URIComponent(e.toString()))}createCookie("___utmvc",res,20)}function simpleDiges
t(mystr){var res=0;for(var i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){res+=mystr.charCodeAt(i)}retu
rn res}function createCookie(name,value,seconds){if(seconds){var date=new Date()
;date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));var expires="; expires="+date.toGMT
String()}else{var expires=""}document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"}f
unction test(o){var res="";var vArray=new Array();for(test in o){switch(o[test])
{case"exists":try{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+typeof(eval(
test)))}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}break;case
"value":try{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+eval(test).toStrin
g())}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}break;case"pl
ugins":try{p=navigator.plugins;pres="";for(a in p){pres+=(p[a]["description"]+" 
").substring(0,20)}vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugins="+pres)}cat
ch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugins="+e)}break;case"plugin":
try{a=navigator.plugins;for(i in a){f=a[i]["filename"].split(".");if(f.length==2
){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin="+f[1]);break}}}catch(e){vArr
ay[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin="+e)}break}}vArray=vArray.join();re
turn vArray}var o={navigator:"exists","navigator.vendor":"value",opera:"exists",
ActiveXObject:"exists","navigator.appName":"value",platform:"plugin",webkitURL:"
exists","navigator.plugins.length==0":"value"};try{setIncapCookie(test(o));docum
ent.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+Math.random()}
catch(e){img=document.createElement("img");img.src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFS
R=1&e="+e}})();</script><script>(function() { var z="";var b="7472797B7661722078
68723B76617220743D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528293B76617220737461747573
3D227374617274223B7661722074696D696E673D6E65772041727261792833293B77696E646F772E
6F6E756E6C6F61643D66756E6374696F6E28297B74696D696E675B325D3D22723A222B286E657720
4461746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D65
6E742822696D6722292E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C
555243543D363726743D373826643D222B656E636F6465555249436F6D706F6E656E742873746174
75732B222028222B74696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B69662877696E646F772E584D
4C4874747052657175657374297B7868723D6E657720584D4C48747470526571756573747D656C73
657B7868723D6E657720416374697665584F626A65637428224D6963726F736F66742E584D4C4854
545022297D7868722E6F6E726561647973746174656368616E67653D66756E6374696F6E28297B73
7769746368287868722E72656164795374617465297B6361736520303A7374617475733D6E657720
4461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2072657175657374206E6F7420696E69746961
6C697A656420223B627265616B3B6361736520313A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67
657454696D6528292D742B223A2073657276657220636F6E6E656374696F6E2065737461626C6973
686564223B627265616B3B6361736520323A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454
696D6528292D742B223A2072657175657374207265636569766564223B627265616B3B6361736520
333A7374617475733D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B223A2070726F6365
7373696E672072657175657374223B627265616B3B6361736520343A7374617475733D22636F6D70
6C657465223B74696D696E675B315D3D22633A222B286E6577204461746528292E67657454696D65
28292D74293B6966287868722E7374617475733D3D323030297B706172656E742E6C6F636174696F
6E2E72656C6F616428297D627265616B7D7D3B74696D696E675B305D3D22733A222B286E65772044
61746528292E67657454696D6528292D74293B7868722E6F70656E2822474554222C222F5F496E63
617073756C615F5265736F757263653F535748414E45444C3D353238343936313938333732343733
393534322C3239343135383533343939333730393439362C31313138373735393633303935393534
323637302C3339333836222C66616C7365293B7868722E73656E64286E756C6C297D636174636828
63297B7374617475732B3D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528292D742B2220696E6361
705F6578633A20222B633B646F63756D656E742E637265617465456C656D656E742822696D672229
2E7372633D222F5F496E63617073756C615F5265736F757263653F4553324C555243543D36372674
3D373826643D222B656E636F6465555249436F6D706F6E656E74287374617475732B222028222B74
696D696E672E6A6F696E28292B222922297D3B";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseI
nt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('Strin
g.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();</script></head><body><iframe style="display:none;
visibility:hidden;" src="http://my.incapsula.com/public/ga/jsTest.html" id="gaIf
rame"></iframe></body></html>
```

Comment: Are you supposed to literally use the `"...."` or does that represent something? Because I tried and it gives me the same result...

Comment: updated my answer.  Also try to google for User-Agent for samples

Comment: Thats still not right: the correct code is something like:
<html>
<head>
 <title>Anime - MyAnimeList.net</title>
    <meta name="Description" content="Start cataloging anime you've watched or manga you've read. Browse through our extensive anime and manga database. Get anime or manga suggestions, recommendations and reviews. View top rated anime and manga. Create anime and manga favorites. Tons more too!" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="anime, animelist, myanimelist, anime list, log anime seen, catalog anime watched, anime reviews, top anime, ... that's the start when using chrome

Comment: I checked their website further and noticed that MyAnimeList.net seems to use https://my.incapsula.com/ which uses a captcha to verify computer users when it thinks you are a bot. The code i get back from the site contains <META NAME="robots" ... so it seems that the website knows that it is being accessed by a bot. So is there anyways to bypass it? It worked fine with Google Chrome (Never got to a capcha thing), and I even got JAVAFX's demo browser to work... so I don't understand what's wrong, if the User-Agent thing is enough to make the site think you are a computer...

Comment: Probably the site that you are calling has to implement (who knows what code).  Try to access the my.incapsula.com site directly and work through any hurdles you meet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46481/discussion-between-rweqx-and-user2310289)

Comment: I put chrome as a user agent and it worked until I passed in Bearer Token then it did not work. Sad.