# Get webpage source code by PC

Tags: java

I am trying to get web page source code using java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            oracle.openStream(), "UTF-8"));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

But the problem is I can only get mobile page, I wanna get the PC page

Please help me, Thanks! XD

Comment: it is a matter of user-agent

Comment: you need to set the user agent, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9828691/1113392)

Comment: Perhaps the web page source does not want to be gotten.