# Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL JAVA Reddit JSON

Tags: java, json, reddit

I am trying to get the JSON file found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/arabfunny/top.json?limit=100

I have the following code:

```
static void getPost() throws Exception {
    String webPage = "https://www.reddit.com/r/arabfunny/top.json?limit=100";

    URL url = new URL(webPage);
    URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
    request.connect();

    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
    JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
}
```

This code throws the following error when run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL: https://www.reddit.com/r/arabfunny/top.json?limit=100
```

Comment: HTTP Status Code 429: The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

Comment: Why is my code sending more than one request?

I only want it to download the file once.

What should I look at/change?

Comment: How many times did you test your code in a short period of time?  Each test counts as 100 requests.

Comment: Using Spring Boot you can make use of [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), you can see a quick guide [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template). This will help you to consume Api rest by http method very easily.

Comment: This was the first time, how can I make it do just one request?

Comment: The URL works fine in my browser.  You might have to set the User-Agent to pretend your code is coming from a standard browser.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection

Comment: I had to set a user agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding:

```
request.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix problem is set **Content type** to `UrlConnection`

```
request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
```

Full code:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String webPage = "https://www.reddit.com/r/arabfunny/top.json?limit=100";

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");

        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(rootobj);
    }
}
```

[image: Output-json]

Comment: This does not work and still returns Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL: https://www.reddit.com/r/arabfunny/top.json?limit=100

Comment: Retry review example and effectively not working first execution but is problem of rest **arabfunny**, second execution was success.