# get source web page's source code, javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to get a web page's source code with java 1.8.0_221. (support TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2)
I tried Jsoup, URLConnection, HttpURLConnection, none of them works, same error. Could anyone give me some suggestions, thank you!

```
html = Jsoup.connect("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=vehicle").get().html();
```

`error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake`

```
html = Jsoup.connect("https://spectrum.ieee.org/rss/energy/fulltext").get().html();
```

`error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

Answer (score 0):

In my browser,

```
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=vehicle
```

redirects to

```
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=vehicle&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en
```

Maybe you need to specify a [browser user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection) in your code.

Comment: still get this error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake