# Failing to download pdf file from URL in java

Tags: java, http, pdf, download

I'm trying to download a PDF file from this particular URL

`https://tesco.sk/akciove-ponuky/letaky-a-katalogy/letak/2023-11-01/263/?download=1`

It just hangs on receiving the response

I've tried with Postman, curl, wget and browsers and it went through.

When I tried in java I'm failing miserably. I've tried several libraries

Example:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("https://tesco.sk/akciove-ponuky/letaky-a-katalogy/letak/2023-11-01/263/?download=1")
            .asString();
```

```
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("https://tesco.sk/akciove-ponuky/letaky-a-katalogy/letak/2023-11-01/263/?download=1").openStream());
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("file.pdf")) {
            byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: This worked for me

`curl --location 'https://tesco.sk/akciove-ponuky/letaky-a-katalogy/letak/2023-11-01/263/' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
--output file.pdf --verbose`

I've tried java libs with this user-agent header but with no luck

Comment: I've just tried using fresh docker container and it worked for me there too `curl --location 'https://tesco.sk/akciove-ponuky/letaky-a-katalogy/letak/2023-11-01/263/' --header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' --output file.pdf --verbose`

The problem is that I'm not allowed to use curl or any other OS tool

Comment: Note: In modern Java there's no need to muck around with `dataBuffer`; you can copy everything from input to output with `in.transferTo(fileOutputStream)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828691/636009

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this particular case. I'm not sure if it will be of any help for other/similar problems but I'll post it here as a reference

```
public File download(URL url) throws FileDownloadException {
        val client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL)
            .build();

        try {
            val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(url.toURI())
                .build();
            val destination = Files.createTempFile("file", ".pdf");
            return client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFile(destination)).body().toFile();
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new FileDownloadException("Failed to download: " + url, e);
        }
    }
```

I tend to think that the problem was around HTTP/2 and with this approach (using HTTP Client) I was able to sort it out. As per documentation

> If set to HTTP/2, then each request will attempt to upgrade to HTTP/2. If the upgrade succeeds, then the response to this request will use HTTP/2 and all subsequent requests and responses to the same origin server  will use HTTP/2. If the upgrade fails, then the response will be handled using HTTP/1.1

So it should work for my failing case and potentially all the others, which my tests actually have proven.